# What's the meaning of '<' and '>' surrounding an OCaml type definition?

Tags: ocaml

I ran across some OCaml code with this type definition:

```
type thread = < run : thread list ; block : bool >
```

What's the meaning of '<' and '>' in this definition?  It almost looks like a record declaration - is it just an alternative syntax for a record declaration?

Comment: It's an [object type](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/types.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents an object type. For this example it's the type of objects with methods named `run` and `block`, and no other methods.

Comment: so does the run method take a thread list argument?  And the block method takes a bool?